# How to choose parameters for Buffer table in Clickhouse?

Tags: buffer, clickhouse

I want to create a buffer table to reduce the number of small inserts, but I don't understand how to select parameters for the table?
For example, I want the buffer table to flash the data to the target table every 4 hours or when the number of rows reaches 10000. But there are other parameters such as min\max bytes and num_layers.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the `max_bytes` parameter to a high enough value so that it doesn't trigger a flush before 100,000 rows or 4 hours.

The `num_layers` is actually the number of buffers - useful if you're inserting lots of data quickly to parallelize the work....but it seems like in your use case this is not a requirement. You should just set `num_layers` to 1.

In other words:

```
CREATE TABLE my_buffer_table 
AS my_destination_table 
ENGINE = Buffer(
    default, --db name
    my_destination_table, --table name
    1, --num_layers
    60, --min_seconds (put whatever you want here)
    14400, --max_seconds (4 hours)
    1000, --min rows (put whatever you want here)
    100000, --100,000 max rows
    100, --min bytes (something small)
    500000000 --max bytes (you need something smart here)
);
```

Because you don't want the last parameter to trigger a flush, make sure that value is bigger than 100,000 rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

engine=Buffer(destination_db, destination_table, ...)
should be tune with only one rule

The result of flushed part in the destination table shall not be small or shall be created no more one time per second.

Check

```sql
SELECT 
  toStartOfHour(event_time) AS dt, 
  quantiles(0.5,0.9)(rows) AS buffer_rows, 
  count() / 3600 AS flushes_per_second 
FROM system.part_log 
WHERE 
  dababase='destination_db' AND table='destination_table' 
  AND event_date=today() AND event_type='NewPart'
```

if flushes_per_second > 1 and rows < 100 000
you will have lot of small background merges in merge tree and have select performance degradation for fresh data